# ps -aux -U "user" not filtering on user as expected

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ps

I have a quick question. I would regularly like to list all the processes running under my account on Linux. After reading the manpage, I thought I'd have to write:

```
ps -aux -U "joshua"
```

to get all processes running under user account `joshua`. However, this command also lists processes running as root and other accounts. Am I missing something? Why does this happen?

Thank you in advance,
Joshua

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `a` flag selects all processes, and `-U` doesn’t *limit* the process selection — in other words, process selection is only additive.

If you drop the `a` flag you’ll get the results you’re looking for:

```
ps ux -U joshua
```

With `-U`, `x` is redundant, so this gives the same results:

```
ps u -U joshua
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and clear answer! But what should I then use instead of a to make sure I get processes running under my user in all states?

Comment: The command I gave in my answer lists all your user’s processes in all states. In fact it can list more than `ps aux` because it includes processes running as another user but started by you (*e.g.* setuid binaries); run `diff -u <(ps aux | grep joshua) <(ps u -U joshua)` to verify. You can use `-u joshua` if you want to filter by effective uid (same as `ps aux | grep joshua`).